# Archive a csv list of subfolders

Tags: batch, archiving, windows-server

I am working in a directory `test` with the following contents

- subdir1
- subdir2
- subdir3
- ...
- subdirxxx

I have a csv list with the names of subdirs that I need to include to my archive, say:

```
subdir2, subdir4, subdir7
```

I need to add the subdirs(and their contents) from the CSV list to a .zip archive, maintaining the paths.

I have a pseudo-working line:

```
for /f "delims=*" %%i in (list.csv) do (xcopy "path\to\maindir\" "path\to\a\newdir" /S /E
```

and then i manually archive the new folder, but I would like to automate this process.

Edit:

I don't need to copy the `list.csv` subdirs to a new directory, I need to archive the subdirs and files from the list to a .zip archive, preserving the directory tree. The archive should have the following structure:

> test\subdir2\
>
> test\subdir4\
>
> test\subdir7\
>
> and so on...

Comment: Yes, you can automate that and see example logic here: https://superuser.com/questions/1300346/how-to-recompress-many-zips-on-a-drive/1302473#1302473 using 7Zip. Essentially you can use the `7Z.exe a "%%~Fi" "path\to\a\newdir\%%~Ni.zip"` but here is another example post too https://superuser.com/questions/1188394/using-a-batch-file-to-zip-files-as-individual-zip-files/1188406#1188406 just give it a test run and try to confirm.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT i've updated the question

Comment: Oh yes, that makes sense—I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @PimpJuiceIT 
I ended up with something like this:

```
@ECHO ON

SET SourceDir=drive:\path\to\source
SET DestDir=drive:\path\to\destination
SET PathToCSV=drive:\path\to\list.csv



for /f "delims=*" %%i in ("%PathToCSV%") do (xcopy "%SourceDir%\%%~i" "%DestDir%\%%~i\" /S /E /I)

pause
CD /D "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"
 7z.exe a "%DestDir%\zipfile.zip" "%DestDir%"

pause
```

This is probably not the best practice regarding disk space, so it should be used WITH CARE on large chunks of data.

Comment: Your xcopy command doesn't include any reference to the for variable containing the iterated subdir, so how should that solve the problem?

Comment: I've updated the command. However this way I get prompted every time for creating a new directory. I am currently trying to figure out how to tell `xcopy` that I want to automatically create the directories.

Comment: Found out that I was missing the trailing slash on %DestDir%\%%~i\ and the /I switch